# jquery trigger click multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, click

I have a tabs with 4 links.

I want click it via jQuery. I use this for first link:

```
$("a[data-search='a1']").delay(2000).trigger('click');
```

it works.

Now also I want do it for other link:

```
$("a[data-search='a1']").delay(2000).trigger('click');
$("a[data-search='a2']").delay(2000).trigger('click');
$("a[data-search='a3']").delay(2000).trigger('click');
$("a[data-search='a4']").delay(2000).trigger('click');
```

but it runs only once for first trigger.

also I tried interval  method (please don't suggest it). I think 
I can not use trigger('click') multipile.

what's the wrong?

live demo: https://jsfiddle.net/1fvqvjb3/8/

Comment: What are you trying to do with the trigger?

Comment: please check demo. it's a full code.

Comment: That javascript does nothing at all in the fiddle.

Comment: because of fiddle. in local server works.

Answer (score 1):

I could be mistaken on what it is you're trying to do, but it appears as if you want each link to be clicked in succession. The jQuery `.delay()` function is non-blocking, so it does **not** wait 2 seconds between each click; rather, there will be a single 2 second delay and then all 4 links will be clicked at the same time, which would certainly seem to appear as though only one link were being clicked.

I'm not sure what you mean by the "interval method" that you do not want suggested, but perhaps the best way to solve your problem is to use `setTimeout()`.

```
(function f(i) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('a[data-search="a' + i + '"]').click();
        if (i < 4) f(i+1);
    }, 2000);
})(1);
```

This is an example of an IIFE, which I highly suggest [reading up on](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/) if you're not already familiar with them.

Comment: Thanks a lot. but see, If I replace `alert(i);` with `$('a[data-search="a' + i + '"]').click();` it runs 4 times normally with right i value. but with `click()` it only runs once! even if add alert,the alert runs once. I hope you underestand me. that is my problem.